A conjecture related to Frankl's conjecture
Let $\mathcal{F}\subseteq2^{[n]},\emptyset\in\mathcal{F}$ be an union-closed family of sets. For $S\in\mathcal{F}$, let $w(S)$ be the number of subsets of $S$ in $\mathcal{F}$. Does there always exist real numbers $a_1,a_2,...,a_n\geq1$ such that $\prod_{i=1}^na_i=|\mathcal{F}|$ and for every $S\in\mathcal{F}$, $\prod_{i\in S}a_i\geq w(S)$?
Motivation: Let $w_i$ be the number of sets of $\mathcal{F}$ that contain $i$. If the above conjecture true, we have $\sum_{i=1}^n\ln a_iw_i\geq\sum_{S\in\mathcal{F}}\ln w(S)$, so we just have to prove $\sum_{S\in\mathcal{F}}\ln w(S)\geq\sum_{i=1}^n\ln a_i\frac{|\mathcal{F}|}{2}=\frac{|\mathcal{F}|\ln|\mathcal{F}|}{2}$ that would imply Frankl's conjecture.

Wait, so you don't know if an affirmative answer to your question implies Frankl's conjecture? You need to prove something else as well? (Just making sure I understand.)

@mathworker21 If my conjecture, together with the last inequality is true, then the Frankl's conjecture is true. In other way, if my conjecture is true, we just need to prove the last inequality to prove the Frankl's conjecture.

do you count $S$ itself in the definition of $w(S)$ or is it just proper subsets of $S$? i.e.: are all the $w(S) \geq 2$ because every $S$ contains the empty set and $S$ itself?

@mhum count itself too

Ah, I think I see. When $\mathcal{F} = 2^{[n]}$, then we can take $a_i = 2$ for all $i$ and the inequality is tight.


so we just have to prove $\sum_{S\in\mathcal{F}}\ln w(S)\geq \dots\frac{|\mathcal{F}|\ln|\mathcal{F}|}{2}$

This inequality does not depend on the choice of $a_i$'s, and, unfortunately, it can  fail. For instance, let $n=3$ and $\mathcal F=\{\emptyset,\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$). Then $|\mathcal F|=5$, $\sum_{S\in\mathcal{F}}\ln w(S)=\ln 1+3\ln 2+\ln 5$ and $\frac{|\mathcal{F}|\ln|\mathcal{F}|}{2}=\frac{5\ln 5}{2}$.
But
$$\ln 1+3\ln 2+\ln 5-\frac{5\ln 5}{2}=3\cdot\left(\ln 2-\frac{\ln 5}{2}\right)<0.$$
